# How to load array properly after terminate the app

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

I am trying to make favorites page according to selected News. I have a custom object and I use `userDefaults` to save it. I followed this to add my custom object into the userDefaults. https://medium.com/flawless-app-stories/save-custom-objects-into-userdefaults-using-codable-in-swift-5-1-protocol-oriented-approach-ae36175180d8. It works fine but when I terminating the app and openinf again if I select new favorite news my previous list disappearing. Only showing the latest selected news.

```
import Foundation

class SelectedArticle{
    static let shared = SelectedArticle()
    
    var selectedNews: Articles! = nil
        
}
```

I create Singleton Class :

```
import Foundation
  class FavoritesArray{

    static let shared = FavoritesArray()
    
    var favoriteArray = [Articles]()
  
}
```

NewsDetailViewController :

```
   class NewsDetailViewController: UIViewController {

   

       //MARK: UserDefaults
        let favorites = UserDefaults.standard
        
       @IBAction func addFavoritesButtonClicked(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        if let selectedData = SelectedArticle.shared.selectedNews{
        
            do {
        
           FavoritesArray.shared.favoriteArray.append(selectedData)
            try favorites.setObject(FavoritesArray.shared.favoriteArray, forKey: "userFavorites")
            Alert.showAlert(on: self, with: "Favorite", Message: "Succesfully added")
        }catch{
            Alert.showAlert(on: self, with: "Warning", Message: error.localizedDescription)
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}
}
```

This my FavoritesViewController :

```
   class FavoritesViewController: UIViewController {
        let favorites = UserDefaults.standard
         var favoriteArticles = FavoritesArray.shared.favoriteArray
    
     override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
            super.viewWillAppear(animated)
            tableView.reloadData()
            getDataFromUserDefaults()
    
        }
             
private func getDataFromUserDefaults(){

      do {
          favoriteArticles = try favorites.getObject(forKey: "userFavorites", castTo: [Articles].self)

           tableView.reloadData()

          } catch {
              print(error.localizedDescription)
           }
       }
}
```

This is my NewsDetailViewController. I clicked on favorite button.

This is my `favoriteViewController` after I add few news :
[image]

When I terminate the app and add another news to my favorite, the list looks like this. I can see the previous favorite list. But If I add new favorite news all previous news disappear and the most recently added news appears on the list :
[image]

Comment: Where does 'SelectedArticle.shared.selectedNews' come from?

Comment: When you load the data you put it in the `favoriteArticles` property, but when you save the data you refer to `FavoritesArray.shared.favoriteArray` - What is keeping those two things in sync.  You should either always use the singleton or always use the view controller property